# How to set the java for different environments

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've windows 64 bit system. 
**In this I have installed java 64 bit version and I've downloaded the eclipse indigo of 64 bit also. I've set the JAVA_HOME path to this 64 bit java installation location. I'm using this for J2EE development. Everything is fine up to this.**

**Now I've downloaded the 32 bit version of java and installed in my system and also I have downloaded 32 bit version of eclipse. Now I want to use this for android development. So how could I set the class path of this 32 bit version java.**

How could I use both on my machine.

I'm looking for your replies.

Thanks

Comment: I am confused. Why use a 32bit JDK on a 64bit machine? The JDK you are using for compiling the code does not really matter. The produced bytecode does not contain any 32bit or 64bit information. So you could stick to your 64bit development environment for producing code that is runnable on 32bit machines, too. The only thing that matters is the Java version.

Answer (score 2):

What matters is not what is used for running Eclipse but what is used for compiling your code.  You can set this @

windows->preferences-java-installed JREs

Answer (score 0):

The build environment uses different java version based on the configuration. you can install any number of Java version (X86 or X64).